# Proxy error from backend api to front end react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I keep getting this error, I have used node & express at the back end and react at the front end

'Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/profile from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:4321/.
[1] See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).'

Answer (score 1):

In my node server, I added
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); in my app.use function. My function finally looks like this:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  next();
});
```

I didn't mess around with the package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a proxy inside the react package.json? This error usually happens when you dont add the proxy.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please also show how he should do it by providing some example in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

your proxy's port should be the same as that of your backend server's listening port.

for e.g in your case set the listening port of you backend sever to 4321.